# Grails 2 not serving static resources

Tags: static, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.0.4 and would like to serve some static resources, such as images or videos.

I have the png version of the grails logo in images/grails_logo.png (as usual). If I type in the url 'http://localhost:8080/TmmWeb/static/images/grails_logo.png', it will show me this logo.

But if I put in 'http://localhost:8080/TmmWeb/static/images/grails_logo.jpg' (there is also a jpeg version of the old logo present), the application shows an 404 report that "The requested resource () is not available.".

If I create a subdirectory 'videos', and change the configuration line for the adhoc patterns to be `grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*','/videos/*']`, then the url 'http://localhost:8080/TmmWeb/static/images/grails_logo.png' also fails with that complaint.

If I set the adhoc patterns are set to null with `grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = []` then urls like 'http://localhost:8080/TmmWeb/videos/grails_logo.png' work and deliver the content.

So why is it that with the adhoc filters in place only .png files can be served from images directory, not from the videos directory and that .jpg files can't be served?

Since these urls fail, embedding the images or a video in a page is also failing when using those urls.

I should also note that ultimately I want to be able to access an entire directory of videos without entering each of them into a resource declaration.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with Grails 2.1.1.

Comment: I create another directory to put some static files but I always got the error 404.

Comment: I don't know why my code is working now, maybe it was a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here turned out to be rather complicated. The new 1.2 version of the Resources plugin contains a full explanation in its user guide.

Briefly, the items allowed by the ad-hoc filters will receive a redirect response to the corresponding item under the /static URI webspace.

Any files under the web-app base directory will be served at a corresponding location under the /static URI webspace, even if they are not listed in the ad-hoc patterns filters.

This behavior will be true for 1.1.x and the 1.2 versions of the Resources plugin. It does not relate to the Grails version being used.